Joomla web site /administrator 504 Gateway Time-out nginx
I have a site that uses Joomla and that works correctly, at least on the public part because as soon as I want to access the admin part with the administrator I get a "504 Gateways Time-Out nginx" error that I don't understand. I can't find any solution to my problem. Please note that my site is hosted on Amen.fr
I have no idea where the problem might be coming from. I think it's coming from Amen.fr, but they tell me they don't do any debugging on the sites. This problem needs to be corrected as a matter of urgency, and access to administrators needs to be restored.

I don't have any "public_html" and I'm not sure how to explain it, but it's a project I've recovered and the version is really not recent.

Ah, you can see the public part of your website. How long does the admin panel take to fail? 30 seconds?

It tells me 1 minute when my console F12 and yes I have FTP access

OK, so there is a fault in Joomla, and the web server is timing out.

See if you can find some logs to see what the fault is.

Another approach is to build a copy locally and debug it as any PHP program.

In my php.ini my log directory is correctly entered and I have activated the logs but nothing in my file which is supposed to contain them. And yes, I've already thought of this option, but the code is in php 5.3, which makes it difficult to debug.

I assume you are referring to PHP/Apache logs. Does Joomla maintain its own logs, in a text file or a database table?

Yes I think so but I don't know where, the tree structure is really weird and the only logs I have thanks to FTP date back to 2014.

See if you can find a Joomla consultant to help you dig into the fault. It sound like you might have a rebuild on your hands.

My host replied, and I quote:
"The nginx used to serve SSL certificates on this type of hosting has a timeout of 60s to wait for the upstream website before giving a 504 error.
This is a system-wide nginx setting that is a normal default that we don't want to change.
It's very likely that this is a temporary slowdown on the upstream website, but if the problem persists, the customer should check the performance of their upstream website, as it may be that a not-very-optimized page takes longer than 60 seconds to respond."

Yes, quite right: a page should not take more than a second or two to generate. What is the "upstream" nature of your website? If Nginx is used as a load balancer, is the website on Apache on a different server in the same provider's network?

Could you SSH into your web server box and try the site from there? (This depends on whether your provider gives you SSH access). I think you have a problem at the PHP/Joomla level, but there is no harm in checking connectivity.
